# Using cURL and dom to scrape data with php

Tags: php, domdocument, getelementsbytagname

Hi i am using cURL to get data from a website i need to get multiple items but cannot get it by tag name or id. I have managed to put together some code that will get one item using a class name by passing it through a loop i then pass it through another loop to get the text from the element.

I have a few problems here the first is i can see there must be a more convenient way of doing this. The second i will need to get multiple elements and stack together ie title, desciption, tags and a url link.

```
# Create a DOM parser object and load HTML
$dom    = new DOMDocument();
$result = $dom->loadHTML($html);

$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '),     'classname')]");

$tmp_dom = new DOMDocument(); 
foreach ($nodes as $node) 
{
    $tmp_dom->appendChild($tmp_dom->importNode($node,true));
}

$innerHTML = trim($tmp_dom->saveHTML()); 

$buffdom = new DOMDocument();
$buffdom->loadHTML($innerHTML);

# Iterate over all the <a> tags
foreach ($buffdom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) 
{
    # Show the <a href>
    echo $link->nodeValue, "<br />", PHP_EOL;
}
```

I want to stick with PHP only.

Comment: Are you saying this doesn't work at all, or it only gets one element?

Comment: it works i need to find a way to get multiple elements

Comment: "Multiple elements". Are you saying the last  `foreach` only loops once? Can you examine the `innerHTML` directly? Have you tried `print_r($buffdom)`? It helps to narrow down the problem.

Comment: the code as is there does work fine. I think it is more my php skill that is lacking. The website i am retrieving the data from has multiple bits of data i want to extract. I want to extract this data and store it in a db later but for now i want to just display each one in plain text. For Example      Title1, Desc1, Tag1 <br> Title2, Desc2, Tag2 etc

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if your problem is in the line:

```
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '),     'classname')]");
```

As it stands, this literally looks for nodes that belong to the class with the name 'classname' - where 'classname' is not a variable, it's the actual name.  This looks like you might have copied an example from somewhere - or did you literally name your class that?

I imagine that the data you are looking may not be in such nodes. If you could post a short piece of the actual HTML you are trying to parse, it should be possible to do a better job guiding you to a solution.

As an example, I just made the following complete code (based on yours, but adding code to open the `stackoverflow.com` home page, and changing `'classname'` to `'question'`, since there seemed to be a lot of classes with `question` in the name, so I figured I should get a good harvest. I was not disappointed.

```
<?php
// create curl resource
        $ch = curl_init();

        // set url
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://stackoverflow.com");

        //return the transfer as a string
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        // $output contains the output string
        $output = curl_exec($ch);

        // close curl resource to free up system resources
        curl_close($ch);      
//print_r($output);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($output);

$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), 'question')]");
print_r($nodes);

$tmp_dom = new DOMDocument(); 
foreach ($nodes as $node) 
    {
    $tmp_dom->appendChild($tmp_dom->importNode($node,true));
    }
  $innerHTML.=trim($tmp_dom->saveHTML()); 

  $buffdom = new DOMDocument();
  @$buffdom->loadHTML($innerHTML);
    # Iterate over all the <a> tags
    foreach($buffdom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
        # Show the <a href>
        echo $link->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
    echo "<br />";
    }
?>
```

Resulted in many many lines of output. Try it - the page is at http://www.floris.us/SO/scraper.php

(or paste the above code into a page of your own).  You were very, very close!

NOTE - this doesn't produce all the output you want - you need to include other properties of the node, not just print out the `nodeValue`, to get everything. But I figure you can take it from here (again, without actual samples of your HTML it's impossible for anyone else to get much further than this in helping you...)